# Other than Contributor, what Azure Role will allow the execution of Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-automation

I have a Powershell script that is used to deploy an *Azure Cloud Service (Classic)*. Up until today, the app user was assigned a `Contributor` role. Part of tightening security, we are revoking this `Contributor` Role as it is too broad.

Part of the deployment process is to update the AutoScaling settings of the production slot using [`Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermautoscalesetting):

```
Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -Location "East US" -Name $scalingName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -TargetResourceId $targetResourceId -AutoscaleProfile $autoscaleProfile
```

As the Azure User is no longer assigned the role of `Contributor`, this command now fails saying it is "Forbidden":

```
Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:Forbidden, Reason phrase: Forbidden
At C:\Path\AzureRMTools.psm1:131 char:5
+     Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -Location "East US" -Name $scalingNam ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Autoscale.AddAzureRmAutoscaleSettingCommand
```

I have tried assign the user many different Roles (Roles I think would have this permission) - but none of them seem to have permission to allow me to execute this.

I would like to know which Role would contain this permission? If none, is it possible to crate a new Role that will allow the execution of the command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) for the nudge in the right direction.

There didn't seem to be any build in Roles that contained the `Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/write` permission, so following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-powershell) I created a new Role.

Here is the `json` file I created:

```
{
    "Name": "Microsoft Insights Contributor",
    "IsCustom": true,
    "Description": "Allows the creation, edition, and deletion of AutoScaling rules from Microsoft.Insights",
    "Actions": [
        "Microsoft.Insights/*",
        "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/*"
    ],
    "NotActions": [],
    "DataActions": [],
    "NotDataActions": [],
    "AssignableScopes": [
        "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    ]
}
```

Then execute the following to add it to your Azure subscription:

```
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -InputFile '.\Microsoft Insights Contributor.json'
```

Hope this helps someone else

*Note: as I am working with Azure Cloud Services (Classic), I also needed permissions to some `Microsoft.ClassicCompute` resources*

Comment: in this case you should probably mark my answer as the right one, since it technically answers your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Any role that allows `Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/write` over the scope you are interested in should work.

as well as permissions (write) on the resources you are trying to tie autoscale to

Comment: By the looks of it, no Role seems to have this permission - [built-in-roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles). Correct?

Comment: ctrl+f doesnt return any results, so probably not. you can create custom role.

Comment: How can one deduce that `Add-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting` needs the permission `Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/write`. Is this documented, or is this tribal knowledge you have? I feel like it should be mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermautoscalesetting?view=azurermps-6.9.0)

Comment: well, it might be documented somewhere, but i was unable to find it. you see, everything boils down to a simple rest call in azure. that means if you can find any source that will tell you what rest call is being performed in any language\tool you can port it to any other language\tool. i found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-template) example. and the arm template gives away RP call straight away. `"type": "Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings",`

Comment: It turns out I needed [`Microsoft.ClassicCompute/*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftclassiccompute) permissions too. I'm still not entirely sure which permission exactly - but after a lot of trial and error it works

Comment: that is probably because you are trying to update a classic vm (or cloud service), for regular vm you would need `microsoft.compute`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answers, here are the specific roles required when your AutoScale is tied to a Classic Cloud Service:

```
"Microsoft.Insights/AutoscaleSettings/Read",
"Microsoft.Insights/AutoscaleSettings/Write",
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots/roles/write",
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots/roles/read"
```